# Can I prevent my website from being loaded as AMP?

Tags: seo, wordpress, amp

For some unknown reason, Facebook has decided that it wants to load my blog website as an AMP website, which only shows an excerpt and there's no way for the user to see the entire article. The previous behaviour over the past five years has been that clicking the article thumbnail will just open the website normally. Just recently this changed to AMP version. I've made no changes to the website, so I don't know why the sudden change is happening.

Regardless, now all of my past shares load as AMP instead of regular.

Is there a way to stop apps or websites from trying to load my content as AMP? My website's not setup for AMP, nor do I want it to be.